# Ajax requests in MVC 5 not work after publishing to IIS 7.5

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-7.5

I have `asp.net mvc 5` project, which works fine in `visual studio`.  But when I publish it to `iis 7.5` some of the ajax responses stopped not working and the console isn't writing anything.

```
    var data = {};
    data.Id = "12";
    data.MemberId = $('').val();
    data.Price = $('').val();

    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));  // viewing correct json data 

    $.ajax(url, {
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (data) {
            jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);
            processing(jsonObj);
        },
        error: function (xhr, errorText) {
            // don't call this function
            console.log('Error ' + xhr.responseText);
        },
    })
```

but if send empty data (only var data = {}, without Id, MemberId), works fine.

**UPD**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult MyAction (MyJsonObject jsonObject)
{ }  

public class MyJsonObject 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MemberId { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }  
}
```

Comment: can you share the signature of the action you are posting against?

Comment: @BeardedMan question updated

Comment: The problem is solved, controller on the server is running incorrectly, but that is another question.

Answer (score 1):

Reason of the problem may be CORS. You need to give permission.

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

or try to add

> crossDomain: true

to your **ajax** settings

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript) article may be more helpful.